# Java: ClassCastException Integer Error

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at KnapSackWeights$Sack.getWeight(KnapSackWeights.java:124)
at KnapSackWeights.fillKnapSackRecursion(KnapSackWeights.java:93)
at KnapSackWeights.fillKnapSack(KnapSackWeights.java:73)
at KnapSackWeights.main(KnapSackWeights.java:33)
```

Hi, I am working on the knapsack problem where the user input numbers in one line and the first number is the target. However, I keep getting an error that I have specified above. I have googled and I understand the error, but I do not understand why it is thrown in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the line

```
myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(weights);
```

where you add a value of type `int[]` to a structure that you really just intended to contain `Integer` values.  When you retrieve that array back from the structure, the JVM is unable to convert it to an `Integer`.

In order to let the compiler trap this kind of error, it would be a good idea for you to write

```
class Sack extends ArrayList<Integer>
```

which instructs the compiler to ensure that `Integer` values are the only things you can put in the `Sack`.

Of course, that's not a fix for the original error, where you tried to add the `int[]`.  To resolve that, you'll probably want to write some kind of loop - iterate through the array, adding the `int` values inside it one by one.

Comment: KnapSackWeights.java:32: error: no suitable method found for add(int[])
        myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(weights);
                              ^
    method Collection.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int[] cannot be converted to Integer)

Comment: Yes, you still need to fix the original error.  My advice of using `<Integer>` was just to allow the compiler to detect the error for you.  It looks like it's done that.  Now you could implement some kind of loop to add the elements of that array to your `Sack`.

Comment: Alright understood, and would I have to make myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(weights [ ]); and then include in the method as well?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Good answer. My only suggestion is you might also explain that since `Sack` extends `ArrayList` the call `add(weights)` compiles because it is using the generic `add(Object)` method of the `ArrayList` class. I.e. the `add` method of `Sack` does not override the method from `ArrayList` as they have different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(int) not myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(int[]);
weights is int[]

i hope it helps